# High quality public transport trip planner examples? Trip visualization examples?

Tags: visualisation, transportation, design, gui, planning

Do you know high-quality online public transport route/trip planners? I'm looking for sites with recognized usability, most carrier-owned planners are bad or very bad from Human-Computer Interaction point of view.

Also: do you know any papers or works on trip planner GUI design patterns? Example: instead of expandable list with search results we can use the time graph with bars like in Nokia Transit - I just want to see more of such stuff. Thanks!

[image: nokia maps example]

Answer (score 2):

One well known one is [Portland TriMet](http://ride.trimet.org/) - with out more detail of what you are looking for it's hard to suggest things.

Comment: Trimet runs on the [OpenTripPlanner](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki) project

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [zee.gr](http://zee.gr/). This has good visual appearance and with the options for various vehicles and way.